# nettle curve 25519 result of base point * 1

Tags: gmp, elliptic-curve, nettle

I am using [GNU nettle](https://git.lysator.liu.se/nettle/nettle) library. I have the following code:

```cpp
#include <nettle/curve25519.h>

uint8_t result[32], one[32];
for(auto &i : one) i = 0;
one[31] = 1;
curve25519_mul_g(result, one);
```

In the code, I multiplied 1 with the base point. The base point's x-coordinate is 9, so I would expect the result to be 9.

But instead, it gives me this number:
`0xfd3384e132ad02a56c78f45547ee40038dc79002b90d29ed90e08eee762ae715`.

Why does this code not generate 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curve25519 [*clamps*](https://git.lysator.liu.se/nettle/nettle/blob/85fd4910eefca34abee053d3014a819b0e97301b/curve25519-mul-g.c#L57-58) some bits of the scalar to `1` or `0`. Specifically in Curve25519 scalar multiplication:

1. the lowest 3 bits are set to `0`, to ensure the output point is only in the large subgroup, and
2. the highest bit (`2^254`) is set to one, to make sure the implementer does not skip any Montgomery-ladder steps.

After this clamping operation, the scalar multiplication algorithm will be executed. So in Curve25519, a point *cannot* be multiplied with `1`.

---

In your case, however, there is even more going on. nettle uses a little-endian convention in their code. That is, when you execute

```
one[31] = 1;
```

you are actually setting the `2^248` bit to one, *not* the `2^0` bit. Then the clamped value will become `k = 2^254 + 2^248`.

The computation `[2^254 + 2^248] * (9 : 1)` results in `0x15e72a76ee8ee090ed290db90290c78d0340ee4755f4786ca502ad32e18433fd` (big endian), which corresponds with your observation.

Comment: One thing to note.. Nettle curve25519 is not little endian. In the manual and web site, it says so, but it is big endian in practice.. It confused me a lot. They should correct the manual as soon as possible.